# jsreport: Error Ocurred - Error during rendering report mac

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, jsreport

I'm using jsreport with nodejs on mac and I get the following error

I already modified folder permissions and ran as root but it does not work. The sample code literally copied it and paste it directly from the official site https://jsreport.net/learn/pdf-reports-in-nodejs

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var jsreport = require('jsreport');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  jsreport.render("<h1>Hello world</h1>").then(function(out) {
    out.stream.pipe(res);
  }).catch(function(e) {    
    res.end(e.message);
  });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Error:

```
Error during rendering report: Command failed: /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/reports/node_modules/phantom-html-to-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/reports/node_modules/phantom-html-to-pdf/lib/scripts/standaloneScript.js /var/folders/0f/6nfvtgxn069237lpmp00ldvr0000gn/T/jsreport/ee4b46e0-261c-11e7-a041-db0530c5a883settings.html
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default phantomjs@1.9 currently doesn't work on the macOS sierra update, you need to use the phantomjs 2.

https://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf#phantomjs2

> The recipe default installation uses phantomjs@1.9. You can additionally install other versions and use them in parallel.
>
> 1. Install additional phantomjs using `npm install phantomjs-exact-2-1-1`
> 2. Use jsreport studio to switch phantomjs version in properties or set `"template.phantom.phantomjsVersion":"2.1.1"` in api call
>
> You can also set the default phantomjs version globally in the config:
>
> ```
> "phantom": {   
>   "defaultPhantomjsVersion": "2.1.1"
> }
> ```
>
> Note that phantomjs 2 produces different sizes of fonts. Also it doesn't support repeating thead when the table spawns multiple pages.